# Using lapply and order to sort rows in the same column in list alphabetically

Tags: r

I'm trying to order rows in the same column in my list, alphabetically.

```
V1 <- c(5, 2, 4, 2)
V2 <- c("a1", "d2", "c3", "b4")
df1 <- data.frame(V1,V2)

V1 <- c(5:8)
V2 <- c("t5", "t6", "t7", "t8")
df2 <- data.frame(V1,V2)

x <- list(df1, df2)

x <- lapply(x, function(y) data.frame(y, V2 = order(y$V2)))
```

The expected output should be:

```
[[1]]
  V1 V2 
1  5 a1    
2  2 b4    
3  4 c3    
4  2 d2    

[[2]]
  V1 V2 
1  5 t5    
2  6 t6    
3  7 t7    
4  8 t8
```

However, the above output produces an extra column of V2.1, and apparently, it ranked my rows alphabetically instead.

```
[[1]]
  V1 V2 V2.1
1  5 a1    1
2  2 d2    4
3  4 c3    3
4  2 b4    2

[[2]]
  V1 V2 V2.1
1  5 t5    1
2  6 t6    2
3  7 t7    3
4  8 t8    4
```

Could someone point out my mistake?

Comment: `lapply(x, function(i) i[order(i$V2),])` ?

Comment: That works too! Thanks so much Ronak!